# run python script inside Java

Tags: java, python

I need to run a shell command in Windows:

c:\Python27\python.exe c:\probabilistic_cracker\process.py dic2.txt

which is running fine in a command shell.

In Java I do this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("c:\\Python27\\python", " c:\\probabilistic_cracker\\process.py"," dic2.txt"));
    Process p = pb.start();
```

or this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Python27\\python", " c:\\probabilistic_cracker\\process.py"," dic2.txt");
```

in both cases the result is

c:\Python27\python: can't open file ' c:\probabilistic_cracker\process.py': [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: There is a space character before ``c:\...``. Remove that and try again!

Comment: YEEEEESS. I could never imagine that the space would affect it!! There should be NO SPACES AT THE BEGGINING of every argument... tnxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Your command is built correctly but the way you pass it to `ProcessBuilder` isn't, as stated in its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) you pass the args directly the way they are, there's no need to add spaces since the ProcessBuilder will take care of that for you.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Python27\\python", "c:\\probabilistic_cracker\\process.py","dic2.txt");
```

So just removing those whitespaces you have in the beginning of each argument string will do the trick.